# Find y as a function of $t$ if $49y″−98y′+48y= 0 $ , $ \,\, y(2)=3,y′(2)=9.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> ### $$49y″−98y′+48y= 0  \quad\quad\quad \,\, y(2)=3,y′(2)=9.$$

When I solved, I got that my $r_1= \frac67$ and $r_2= \frac87.$ Then I got that $y= C_1e^{(\frac67)}t +C_2e^{\frac87}t.$ I’m not sure how to proceed from here in regards to substituting $y(2)= 3$ and $y’(3)=9$ to get $C_1$ and $C_2$ values.

Answer (score 1):

Take an Ansatz of $y=e^{rt}$. Then

$$49r^2-98r+48=0$$

so we have the the solutions $r_1=\frac67$ and $r_2=\frac87$. Now if

$$y=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t},$$

then the initial conditions give

$$3=c_1e^{12/7}+c_2e^{16/7}\qquad \text{and} \qquad 9=\frac67c_1e^{12/7}+c_2e^{16/7}.$$

This is a linear system with two unknowns and two equations. Unfortunately, the numbers are just ugly. For example,

$$c_1=e^{-12/7}(3-c_2e^{16/7})=3e^{-12/7}-c_2\frac87e^{4/7}.$$

Thus

\begin{align}
9&=\frac67c_1e^{12/7}+\frac87c_2e^{16/7}\\ \\
&=\frac67(3e^{-12/7}-c_2e^{4/7})e^{12/7}+\frac87c_2e^{16/7}\\ \\
&=\frac{18}{7}-\frac67c_2e^{16/7}+\frac87c_2e^{16/7}\\ \\
&=\frac27c_2e^{16/7}+\frac{18}{7}.
\end{align}

Thus $63=2c_2e^{16/7}+18$, so $c_2=\frac{45}{2}e^{-16/7}$. From here the rest will be straightforward.

---

I should add that, if you can solve a system of equations like

$$\begin{cases}2x+3y=1\\ -x+6y=-2\end{cases}$$

(which presumably you can if you are taking differential equations), then you should also be able to solve *any* such system. If the numbers are really horrible to write, you can always use a decimal approximation (if appropriate), or simplify the math by assigning nice labels like $a=67e^{12/7}$ (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
y(2)=\text{C}_1\cdot\exp\left(\frac{6\cdot2}{7}\right)+\text{C}_2\cdot\exp\left(\frac{8\cdot2}{7}\right)=3\\
\\
y'(2)=\frac{6}{7}\cdot\text{C}_1\cdot\exp\left(\frac{6\cdot2}{7}\right)+\frac{8}{7}\cdot\text{C}_2\cdot\exp\left(\frac{8\cdot2}{7}\right)=9
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Which will give:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{C}_1=-\frac{39}{2}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{12}{7}\right)\\
\\
\text{C}_2=\frac{45}{2}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{16}{7}\right)
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Comment: Where is there a mistake? I’m having a problem with simplifying the equations to solve for C1 and C2.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation becomes a lot simpler if you write the general solution based on the initial time,
$$
y(t)=c_1e^{\frac67(t-2)}+c_2e^{\frac87(t-2)}
$$
Then you get the initial conditions in the simple form
$$
3=y(2)=c_1+c_2\\
9=y'(2)=\frac67c_1+\frac87c_2
$$
which can be combined to
$$
6=-\frac17(c_1-c_2)
\implies
\begin{aligned}
2c_1=3-42\\
2c_2=3+42
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: for my final answer, I got y = (-39/2)e^((-6/7)t)+45/2e^((-8/7)t) but apparently it is wrong? Can someone help me.

Comment: You need to replace $t$ with $(t-2)$ to get the solution as in my and the other answers.